# problem for console redirection after piping through command

Tags: .net, vb.net

Im trying to create a menu which can be piped data to, so it generates automatically the menu, the problem im having is that the console input is redirected and cant find any way to reset it back to defaults to read keyboard inputs again.

I've tried :

```
Console.SetIn(New IO.StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput))
```

... after generating the list to regain control, but to not avail.

I also tried to save the console.in state and restoring it after generating the list, but failed again.

:: the code

```
sub main()

  Dim lista As New List(Of String)
        Do
            Dim line = Console.ReadLine()
            Select Case line
                Case vbNullString
                    Exit Do
                Case Else
                    lista.Add(line)
            End Select
        Loop

        For Each linea As String In lista
            Console.WriteLine(linea)
        Next

        Console.ReadKey()
end sub ()
```

lets suppose we compile the code into program.exe and exec the following:

```
dir /b | program.exe
```

all executes ok until the console.readkey () where the error it casts is :

> System.InvalidOperationException: console is redirected from file

.... or something like that (my computer is in another language so no accurate translation)

My question is:
**how do i regain control of the redirected console.in so i can read input keys to make a selection?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution!!!!!!!

Define these win32 api calls:

```
Private Declare Function FreeConsole Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Private Declare Function AttachConsole Lib "kernel32" (ByVal consoleid As Long) As Long
```

And where you want to regain control of console, add the following:

```
  FreeConsole() ' free current attached console
  AttachConsole(-1) ' regain control of parent console
```

And that's it.